# Where is UnBoundFunctionPathSegment in ODataLib 7.5?

Tags: odata, odata-v4

Trying to upgrade from ODataLib 6.4 to ODataLib 7.5 and missing 'UnBoundFunctionPathSegment'in Routing.

Answer (score 1):

All "*PathSegment" wrapper classes defined in the WebApi 6.x have been removed.

We need to use the ODL path segment classes as below:

- BatchReferenceSegment
- BatchSegment
- CountSegment
- DynamicPathSegment
- EntitySetSegment
- KeySegment
- MetadataSegment
- NavigationPropertyLinkSegment
- NavigationPropertySegment
- ODataPathSegment
- OperationImportSegment
- OperationSegment
- PathTemplateSegment
- PropertySegment
- SingletonSegment
- TypeSegment
- ValueSegment

For the specific case of "UnBoundFunctionPathSegment", one should use  "OperationImportSegment" as replacement.

Hope this helps others.